# grep command not match start of new line with another regex

Tags: regex, unix

I have file with this content:

```
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
alex/nfs/location 
/nfs/location/
# /nfs/location/
#alex /nfs/location
alex # d /nfs/location
/nfs/location
```

I want to print all line where path starts with and don't contain #

> /nfs/location/

In my example only line 3 will not match

I wrote unix commad:

```
grep -rE ([^#.*]|^[^0-9aA-zZ]/nfs/location/ .
```

but lines with # also appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select the lines with `/nfs/location` with an additional requirement:
It should be on the start of the line or a non-alnum character must be in front of it. You can use an OR in the expression:

```
echo "path=/nfs/location/alex
path = /nfs/location/
alex/nfs/location
/nfs/location/" |
grep -E "(^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])/nfs/location"
```

Comment: if I want to ignore the comment. for example, #path=/nfs/location or alex # path=/nfs/location @Walter A

Comment: In addition, I want to exclude list of directory without soft link. I don't find how can I do it with list if I want to write script for this

Comment: You can ignore lines with comment with `grep -Ev "#.*/nfs/location"`

Comment: what is about of skip list of directory ? @WalterA

Comment: Thats another kind of question. Post a new question, and explain what you mean with the soft link (`ln -s`?)

Comment: if I run grep -Er  "[^#.*]/nfs/location". it doesn't work, why ? @Walter A

Comment: @Alex: updating an already answered question will confuse new readers, please undo

Comment: You do not need the option `r`. I wanted to pipe the results to `grep -v` excluding thins you do not want. You can try an exact match with `grep -E "^[^#]*[^0-9a-zA-Z#]*/nfs/location/"`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added line to my example @Walter A

Comment: Your asked for lines with a slash after `location`, so `/nfs/location` is skipped. Please move your resulting questions to a new question and restore the original question here.

Comment: Sorry, I won't answer here anymore.

Comment: Why ? @Walter A

Comment: I asked for a new SO question with rew requirements and this question restord to the original state. The example given now doesn't match the requirements, you did not say what is wrong with the regex,. I want to avoid long discussions in comments. Good luck !

Comment: How can I do it ? @Walter A

Answer (score 0):

Try

`grep -e "path\s?=\s?\/nfs\/location\/" test.txt`

Where \s? means that zero or one of a any whitespace character is allowed.

**EDITED**
Sorry, I did not understand your question properly.
Then this is one possible solution:

```
grep -e "=\?\s\?\/nfs\/location\/"
```

Comment: Are you sure ? path is only example of word in file. It is not work @Constantin Butzke

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what are you trying to match, but if you are only trying to match `/nfs/location/` preceded by a whitespace (`\s`), equal sign (`=`), or start of the line anchor (`^`), you can use the [positive look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on `\s|=|^`, like this:

```
$ grep -P '(?<=\s|=|^)/nfs/location' file
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
/nfs/location/
```

(Note, `-P` flag enables PCRE support in `grep`.)

**Edit** (after clarification from comments): to assert a character not in range `[a-zA-Z0-9]` preceding your fixed path, you can use the [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
$ grep -P '(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])/nfs/location' file
path=/nfs/location/alex 
path = /nfs/location/ 
/nfs/location/
```

Comment: I want instead of \s|=|^ write non aA-zZ0-9. How ? @randomir

Comment: I've updated my answer with the negative look-behind assertion alternative.

Comment: @Alex, any success with this answer?